# Jquery nesting when condition

Tags: jquery

To check for callbacks and then run another function I am nesting when inside another when-then condition

Like this

```
$.when(function1()).then(function(){
    //do something
    $.when(function2()).then(function(){
        //do something
        $.when(function3()).then(function(){
            //do something
            function4();
        });
    });
});
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: You don't really need `$.when` here

Comment: How can I wait for function1 to complete?

Comment: `function1().then(...);`

Comment: `is this the right way` ... probably not but it's not clear at all what your goals are

Comment: it is a series of tasks. If only function1 returns true i need to run function2.  Like Wolff said i can remove $.when